# C# - Changing a variable in an event?

Tags: c#, events, integer

*Before reading, I wanted to point out I'm a High School student working in C# and have been doing a majority of my learning from the internet.*

I'm having a problem where when I set `int_player1_religion = 1;` integer in the `pictureBox_buddhism_click` it does not retain the value (or resets it) when I click on `pictureBox_taoism_click`. I need to click on one, then click on the other however both are being counted as a first-time-click when the second needs to recognize that it is the second button being clicked.

I believe the problem lies within setting the integers, but I'm not quite sure where to put them if that is the case. Any idea's on what's wrong? (There will be more buttons than just the current two (Buhhdism and Taoism) but only two clicks to declare player1's and player2's roles.)

Code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int int_player1_religion = 0;  // <=====
    int int_player2_religion = 0;  // <=====
    string string_player1_religion;
    string string_player2_religion;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //1 = buddhism, 12 = celtic polytheism 
        button1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox_buddhism_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (int_player1_religion == 0) {
            int int_player1_religion = 1; // <=====
            string string_player1_religion = "buddhism";
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_buddhism;
            label2.Text = "player 2 choose your religion";
            label3.Text = "";
            pictureBox_buddhism.Visible = false;
            button2.Text = "buddhism";
        }

        if (int_player1_religion != 0)
        {
            int int_player2_religion = 1;  // <=====
            string string_player2_religion = "buddhism";
            pictureBox4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_buddhism;
            label2.Text = "start the game";
            label3.Text = "";
            pictureBox_buddhism.Visible = false;
            button3.Text = "buddhism";
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox_taoism_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int_player1_religion == 0)
        {
            int int_player1_religion = 2;  // <=====
            string string_player1_religion = "taoism";
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_taoism;
            label2.Text = "player 2 choose your religion";
            label4.Text = "";
            pictureBox_taoism.Visible = false;
            button2.Text = "taoism";
        }
        if (int_player1_religion != 0)
        {
            int int_player2_religion = 2;  // <=====
            string string_player2_religion = "taoism";
            pictureBox4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_taoism;
            label2.Text = "start the game";
            label4.Text = "";
            pictureBox_taoism.Visible = false;
            button3.Text = "taoism";
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The <===== comments is where I believe things are going wrong.

Comment: You are creating a locally-scoped variable with the same name as your class-scoped.  The locally-scoped variable goes away when the scope does.  At the end of the if statement.  If you want to set the class variable, just `int_player2_religion = 2`, not `int int_player2_religion = 2;`

Comment: Don't use `if (x)` followed by `if (!x)` -- use `if (x) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to encourage you to keep learning! It's not easy learning C# programming in high school since most people do this in college or on the job.

Anyways, the issue is in your second declaration of

`int int_player1_religion = 1; // <=====`

And in your second declaration of

`int int_player2_religion = 1;`

You see, this statement creates a totally new int_player1_religion variable that is only valid within the if block that you declared it in - even though it shares the same name as the int_player1_religion variable you declared in the first few lines, they actually are totally separate in memory.

In order to modify/access the int_player1_religion variable that you want, take out the "int" part in front of int_player1_religion = 1; and int_player1_religion = 2; everywhere after the 3rd and 4th lines of code where you originally declared it.

Hope this helps!

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int int_player1_religion = 0;  // <=====
    int int_player2_religion = 0;  // <=====
    string string_player1_religion;
    string string_player2_religion;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //1 = buddhism, 12 = celtic polytheism 
        button1.Visible = false;
    }

    private void pictureBox_buddhism_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (int_player1_religion == 0) {
            int_player1_religion = 1; // <===== take out the int
            string string_player1_religion = "buddhism";
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_buddhism;
            label2.Text = "player 2 choose your religion";
            label3.Text = "";
            pictureBox_buddhism.Visible = false;
            button2.Text = "buddhism";
        }

        if (int_player1_religion != 0)
        {
            int_player2_religion = 1;  // <===== take out the int
            string string_player2_religion = "buddhism";
            pictureBox4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_buddhism;
            label2.Text = "start the game";
            label3.Text = "";
            pictureBox_buddhism.Visible = false;
            button3.Text = "buddhism";
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox_taoism_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int_player1_religion == 0)
        {
            int_player1_religion = 2;  // <===== take out the int
            string string_player1_religion = "taoism";
            pictureBox2.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_taoism;
            label2.Text = "player 2 choose your religion";
            label4.Text = "";
            pictureBox_taoism.Visible = false;
            button2.Text = "taoism";
        }
        if (int_player1_religion != 0)
        {
            int_player2_religion = 2;  // <===== take out the int
            string string_player2_religion = "taoism";
            pictureBox4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.religion_taoism;
            label2.Text = "start the game";
            label4.Text = "";
            pictureBox_taoism.Visible = false;
            button3.Text = "taoism";
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```